# Create new sheet of duplicate records and send to destination folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

Looking to add a few functions together but having trouble with it. My goal is to compare two sheets find the duplicate names and send that data to a new spreadsheet in a specific folder. Right now I have a Spreadsheet that has List, Original, and Filter. The List is where I'm looking to find duplicates compared to the Original list and the filter is how I want it to look at the end when the new sheet is created. I'm currently using the formula

=filter(Original!A:F, match(Original!C:C,List!B:B,0)) to achieve the filter and am looking to convert that into google scripts. From the Filter tab I can create the spreadsheet and send it to a specific folder but since it's a formula it'll copy the formula instead of the values. I've heard of using {contents, text only} but I would prefer to have one script that filters, matches, and creates the spreadsheet

Below is the link to the spreadsheet for you guys to check out. Sorry for the long post... Thanks in Advance!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i5ejG0ldB9EIMtaFezbsJNJS5hbdu9RpyJ4134b9q7s/edit#gid=1328732453

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Send Sheet');
  menu.addItem('Create Sheet', 'createSheet')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createSheet(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Get current active sheet.
   
var sheet_name = sheet.getRange("J1").getValue(); // Get the value of cell B1, used to name the new spreadsheet.

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxx"); // Get the ID of the folder where you will place a copy of the spreadsheet.

var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheet_name); // create new blank spreadsheet in a root folder
var asFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId()); // get new spreadsheet as a file

folder.addFile(asFile); // add this file to destination folder
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(asFile); // remove a file from root folder
  
  var copiedSheet = sheet.copyTo(newSS); // copy active sheet to new spreadsheet
copiedSheet.setName(sheet_name); // rename copied sheet
newSS.deleteSheet(newSS.getSheetByName('Sheet1')); // remove "Sheet1" sheet which was created by default in new spreadsheet
}

function filter() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var trn = ss.getSheetByName("Original");
  var originalData = trn.getRange(2, 1, trn.getLastRow()-1,7).getValues();
  var person = "Jonathan";
  
  var data = originalData.filter(function(item){ return item[0] === person });

  var targetSheet = ss.insertSheet(person);
  targetSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: What is the specific question or problem you're having? Is it that your filter() function is copying formulas instead of values?

Comment: No my createSheet function is copying formulas instead of values. I've tried to do {contentsOnly, true} to my copyTo but it didn't work either

Comment: What part of the createSheet function are you talking about? If it is getValue(), then try changing it to getDisplayValue(): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue

Comment: var sheet = Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getDisplayValues(); caused an error stating thats not a function. Changed it to Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getDisplayValues(); same thing.

Comment: Considering that the problem is indeed with `getValue()`, what I meant was to use `sheet.getRange("J1").getDisplayValue()` instead of `sheet.getRange("J1").getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

### `{contentsOnly, true}` only works for the method [range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options), not for [sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)

- As for the method `range.copyTo()`, unfortunately you cannot use it to copy data into a different spreadsheet.
- As a workaround, you can first create an empty sheet in the new spreadsheet, and the copy the data with [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setvaluesvalues)

Sample:

Modify

```js
var copiedSheet = sheet.copyTo(newSS); // copy active sheet to new spreadsheet
copiedSheet.setName(sheet_name);
```

to

```js
var newSheet = newSS.insertSheet();
newSheet.setName(sheet_name);
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var notation = dataRange.getA1Notation();
var values = dataRange.getValues();
newSheet.getRange(notation).setValues(values):
```